# Howto set udev rule to disable intel_pstate turbo on linux?

Tags: udev, rules, turbo-boost

I m looking to make a udev rule that will basically do:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

In order to disable the turbo, how can I do it ? I've never made `udev` rule and I am a bit scared to start with the CPU but I need to disable it.

Comment: I would like to know this as well... I can investigate..

Answer (score 4):

The following rule worked on my machine, placed in /etc/udev/rules.d/50-cpu-custom.rules:

```
KERNEL=="cpu",RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo'"
```

It was the only form that appeared to work. ATTR assignments had no effect or caused errors in /var/log/messages, and could not match anything more specific.